# Remove quotes from new JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a string with currency values. I add those values to a new array like so:

```
console logged number values
var xxc = 5868281.01, 5915961.10, 5748198.74, 5734639.29, 1144897.13;

var m = new Array(xxc);
```

For some reason, when the array is formed, it adds double quotes around my array and it breaks my array when trying to read it.

```
["5868281.01, 5915961.10, 5748198.74, 5734639.29, 1144897.13"]
```

[image]

I've tried to map the values in the array to remove the string using:

```
m.map(s => eval('null,' + s));
```

But that doesnt work. How would i remove the quotes in the array?

Comment: Why it brokes your code? If you can still eval the values as numbers them its ok.

Comment: The code you're showing can't produce that output. There would need to be quotes around all of those numbers. If you want an array, you need brackets around the elements.

Comment: Just do `var xxc = [5868281.01, 5915961.10, 5748198.74, 5734639.29, 1144897.13];`. That’s your array. If you have the string `"5868281.01, 5915961.10, 5748198.74, 5734639.29, 1144897.13"` given, then `split` with `", "`, then optinally `map` with `Number`.

Comment: the data in `xxc` looks like a typo.  If you are receiving all of your values in a string, then you can use `var data = xxc.split(',')`

Comment: @Xufox when its consel logged its fine - but when i print it into my and try to display the array it has the double quotes.

Comment: @MizAkita Do you understand the difference between strings and arrays and how the console displays them? Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var xxc = [] ;

xxc = JSON.parse ([5868281.01, 5915961.10, 5748198.74, 5734639.29, 1144897.13]);

console.log(JSON.strigify(xxc) ;
```

To test, try:

```
console.log(xxc[2]) ;
```

and you should get: `5748198.74`.

Comment: There is no JSON to be parsed here. Why are you using `JSON.parse`?

Comment: This answer worked...i added the brackets [ ] and used JSON.parse... didn't even need to stringify it. Worked perfect thanks!!!!

Comment: @MizAkita You only needed to add the brackets, not parse it. The correct array syntax has been suggested to you about four times.

Comment: @Xufox, `[aaa,bbb]` is a way to specify the contents of an object, or, in other words, a JSON (**J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation). True, the parsing may be omitted from the construction. Still, it works for the PO so...

Comment: @FDavidov Yes, that’s a JavaScript array. It’s neither an object nor JSON. JSON is a string format, not an array.

Comment: @Xufox, the **N** for **NOTATION** says it already. Know what? Want the credited points to be returned or passed to you? Just tell me how and I'll be happy to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line isn't well formed you need something like...

```
var xxc = [5868281.01, 5915961.10, 5748198.74, 5734639.29, 1144897.13];
```

You really don't need to reassign it.

```
var m = xxc;
```

You can check to see if it's in the correct format by logging to console.

```
console.log(m);
```

```js
var xxc = [5868281.01, 5915961.10, 5748198.74, 5734639.29, 1144897.13];

var m = xxc;

console.log(m);
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: I just tried this but it still produces: ["5829224.66, 5819339.77, 5799306.02, 1184226.84"]

Comment: @MizAkita No, it doesn’t. Please, edit your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Xufox FDavidov above's answer worked perfect! Thanks for your help too.